# Need to populate a field in Access 2010 based off of 2 combobox selections

Tags: combobox, ms-access-2010

I have 2 comboboxes [Product_Select] and [Batch_Number_Select]. I need a field in my table to be populated with a certain 2 digit code based on the selections in those comboboxes. I have the combinations already (they're set and will not change) I just need to figure out how to make the thing work. So far, all of my searches have turned up nothing.

For example:

[Product_Select] has 28 choices

[Batch_Number_Select] has 5 choices

If a user selects "24 de malto 50's" (row 14) from the [Product_Select] combobox

and then selects "Batch 2" (row 1) from the [Batch_Number_Select] combobox,

the correct 2 digit code will be "46" (row 45) in the [Final_Number] field

But I'm totally stumped on how to accomplish this.

Comment: No, that's why I'm posting here. I just don't know how to get started.

Comment: Yes, all three are in separate look-up tables.

Comment: Sorry, without a lookup table containing the 3 fields, I don't know how Access can know the correct 2 digit code is "46" when those combo box selections are "24 de malto 50's" and "Batch 2".